# SlideToggle() for menu bar in PHP with jQuery doesn't works

Tags: php, jquery, html, slidetoggle

**I got this codes:**

```
<div id='news' class='menuitem'>
<span onClick="MenuItemAction('news')"> //----- CLICK HERE
....
</span>
</div>
<div id='news_Submenu' class='Submenu'> //----- SLIDE DOWN/UP SHOWING THIS
....
</div>


<div id='forum' class='menuitem'>
<span onClick="MenuItemAction('forum')"> //----- CLICK HERE
....
</span>
</div>
<div id='forum_Submenu' class='Submenu'> //----- SLIDE DOWN/UP SHOWING THIS
....
</div>
```

And this jQuery attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function MenuItemAction(element){
  $(document).click(function(){
    $("#"+element+"_Submenu").slideToggle("medium");
  });
});
```

---

Obs.: I want show/hide the respective `div` on clicking at respective `span`.

Comment: What is it showing in Console? Any error? Have you correctly included  jQuery library?

Comment: no, any error, but the effect slideToggle doesn't work. Sorry i'm newbie on it... jQuery library how so?

Comment: You need jQuery library. Include something of this sort at the top of your page: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a inlined click handler use a jQuery click handler and specify the id of the target element using a `data-*` attribute

You can try something like

```
<div id='news' class='menuitem'>
    <span data-target="news" class="trigger">
        Triger
    </span>
</div>
<div id='news_Submenu' class='Submenu'>
    ....
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).on('click', '.menuitem .trigger', function () {
    $("#" + $(this).data('target') + "_Submenu").slideToggle("medium");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u4SYX/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function MenuItemAction(element) {
   $("#"+element+"_Submenu").slideToggle("medium");
}
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function MenuItemAction(element){
  $(document).click(function(){
    $("#"+element+"_Submenu").slideToggle("medium");
  });
});
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZxtNt/

PS: Dont put this function `MenuItemAction` under `document.ready`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function MenuItemAction(element) {
   $("#"+element+"_Submenu").slideToggle("medium");
}
```

[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbk6L/12/)

Answer (score 0):

changes your codes and try:

```
<div id='news' class='menuitem'>
   <span class="MenuItemAction" id='news'> //----- CLICK HERE
   ....
   </span>
</div>
<div id='news_Submenu' class='Submenu'> //----- SLIDE DOWN/UP SHOWING THIS
   ....
</div>

<div id='forum' class='menuitem'>
   <span class="MenuItemAction" id='forum'> //----- CLICK HERE
   ....
   </span>
</div>

<div id='forum_Submenu' class='Submenu'> //----- SLIDE DOWN/UP SHOWING THIS
   ....
</div>
```

---jquery---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.MenuItemAction').click(function(e){
        var element = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#"+element+"_Submenu").slideToggle("medium");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the function of $(document).ready(func).

The ready function will call the func when DOM is loaded.

What you need is a click event handler. Please try the following:

1 define a script tag

2 Add the MenuItemAction function:

```
function MenuItemAction(element){
    $("#"+element+"_Submenu").slideToggle("medium");
});
```

No need to add it in ready.